# How to make a button inside scroll view interactable. Unity UI 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scroll view and when I place buttons inside it they are not interactable how I can fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm listing down common mistakes which can cause UI intractable issues in Unity:

1. Make sure you have a Game Object with an [`Event System`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/EventSystem.html) and `Standalone Input Module` component attached to it in your Scene, You can create one from `GameObject Menu > UI > Event System`.
   [Screenshot showing the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt6J9.png)
2. Make sure some UI element/Game Object not blocking your clicks(sometimes it happens we have a transparent image over our element which can block input).
3. Make sure there is a `Graphics Raycaster` component attached to the game object which contains a `Canvas` component if you want their child elements to receive input.
4. Make sure your button's `Interactable` property is set to true.
5. Make sure you set the `Raycast Target` property to `true` for your button's `Image`.

Comment: nice! I did a video also that may help someone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihh3i2BqYXE

Answer (score 0):

Is it in the contents box inside the scroll View? If not then put the game object in there